# Find all continuous functions from $ ]0,+\infty[ \to ]0,+\infty[ $ that satisfy $\forall x\in ]0,+\infty[ , f(x) = f(x^a f(x)) $.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, functional-equations

Let  $ a > 1 $. Find all continuous functions from $ ]0,+\infty[ \to   ]0,+\infty[ $ that are solutions to the functional equation $\forall x\in ]0,+\infty[ ,  f(x) = f(x^a f(x)) $.

It's easy to see that

all positive constant functions  are solutions
If $f:  ]0,+\infty[ \to   ]0,+\infty[ $  is invertible, the only solution is $ f(x) =\frac{1}{x^{a-1}} $

Some ideas?

Comment: $x^a f(x)$ is an idempotent function

Comment: Are u sure ? if $h(x)=x^a f(x)$, then $h(h(x))=\frac{(h(x))^{a+1}}{x^a}$

Comment: Right, I misread the question.

Comment: I am familiar with the notation  ℝ_+ meaning (0, ∞). But what does the asterisk superscript mean?

Comment: it  means $]0,+\infty[$.  Notation changed

Comment: Another solution: $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^[a-1}} $ if $ x \leq 1 $ and $ f(x) = 1 $ if $ x \geq 1 $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Claim:** The continuous functions satisfying the equation $f(x) = f(x^af(x))$ are exactly the set of functions of the following form for some constants $c_1,c_2$ such that $0\le c_1\le c_2\le \infty$:$$
f(x) =\begin{cases}\frac1{c_1^{a-1}} & x \le c_1 \\ \frac1{x^{a-1}} &x\in(c_1,c_2)\\\frac1{c_2^{a-1}} & x \ge c_2 \end{cases}
$$

This is clearly continuous on $(0,\infty)$ and it satisfies the functional equation trivially for $x\in(c_1,c_2)$. For $x\le c_1$, we note that $c_1\ge \frac{x^a}{c_1^{a-1}}=x^af(x)$ so we have $\frac1{c_1^{a-1}}=f(x)=f(x^af(x))$. Similarly this $f$ works for $x\ge c_2$. (Note: $f$ is constant if $c_1=c_2$, and $f(x) = \frac1{x^{a-1}}$ if $c_1=0$ and $c_2=\infty$.)

To prove the claim, we'll make use of what I'm going to call the *reflection princple:* If $f$ satisfies the functional equation, then so does $\bar f(x) = \frac1{f(1/x)}$.

Define $h(x) =x^a f(x)$. Then we have $f(x) = f(h(x))$, and $h$ is a continuous function from $(0,\infty)$ to $(0,\infty)$. We will prove the claim as a series of lemmas about $f$ and $h$.

---

**Lemma 1:** $h(x)$ is strictly increasing.

*Proof:* First, we show $h$ is injective. Suppose $h(x)=h(y)$. Then \begin{eqnarray}
&&h(x)=h(y)\\
&\implies& f(h(x))=f(h(y))\\
&\implies& f(x) = f(y)\\
&\implies& \frac{h(x)}{x^a} = \frac{h(y)}{y^a}\\
&\implies& x=y
\end{eqnarray}
Thus $h$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing. If it is decreasing, we may derive a contradiction, because in that case $f(x)=h(x)/x^a$ would also be strictly decreasing (as a product of two decreasing positive functions), and thus in particular $f$ is invertible and therefore $f(x) =\frac1{x^{a-1}}$, which implies $h(x) = x$, which is not decreasing.

**Lemma 2:** The set of points such that $h(x)=x$ is a closed interval in $(0,\infty)$. [Note: In the subspace topology, $(0,\infty)$ and intervals of the form $(0,b]$ are closed though they are not closed in $\mathbb R$.]

*Proof:* We use contradiction to prove the slightly weaker claim that if $A<B$ are real numbers with $h(A) = A$ and $h(B)=B$, then there exists $C\in(A,B)$ such that $h(C)=C$.

Suppose $h$ has no fixed points in $(A,B)$. By the reflection principle, we can suppose without loss of generality that $h(x)>x$ for all $x\in(A,B)$. By injectivity and continuity of $h$, we can see that it is a bijection from $(A,B)$ to itself. Furthermore, it is evident that, for each $x\in(A,B)$, the sequence $\{x,h(x),h(h(x)),\dots\}$ converges to $B$. Therefore, for all $x\in(A,B)$, we have $$
f(x) = f(h(x)) = f(h(h(x))) = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(h^n(x)) = f(B) = B
$$
But this makes $f$ discontinuous at $A$, a contradiction. Therefore $f$ has a fixed point in $(A,B)$.

This implies that, if $A\le B$ are fixed points of $h$, the fixed points of $h$ are dense in $[A,B]$. By continuity of $h$, the set of fixed points is a closed set, and therefore is cannot be anything other than a closed subinterval of $(0,\infty)$.

**Lemma 3:** $h(x)$ has a fixed point.

*Proof:* We again prove by contradiction. Suppose $h(x)\ne x$ for all $x$. By the reflection principle, we may suppose without loss of generality that $h(x)>x$ for all $x$. This implies for any $x$ $$
\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} h^n(x) = \infty
$$
Fix $x_0$ and define $I_n = [h^n(x_0),h^{n+1}(x_0)]$. Let $M=\max_{x\in I} f(x)$. We note that $h(I_{n-1}) = I_n$, thus for each $n$, $f(x)\le M$ for all $x\in I_n$. Because $[x_0,\infty)=\bigcup_{n\ge0} I_n$, we conclude $f(x)\le M$ for all $x\in [x_0,\infty)$. However, this contradicts $h(x)>x$ for all $x$: For $n$ sufficiently large, we have $h^n(M^{-\frac1{a-1}} )\ge x_0$, and thus $$
M^{-\frac1{a-1}} < h(M^{-\frac1{a-1}}) = M^{-\frac a{a-1}}f(M^{-\frac1{a-1}}) = M^{-\frac a{a-1}}f(h^n(M^{-\frac1{a-1}})) \le M^{-\frac a{a-1}} M=M^{-\frac1{a-1}},
$$
a contradiction.

**Lemma 4:** Suppose $h(B)=B$ and $h(x)\ne x$ for all $x>B$. Then $f(x)$ is constant on $[B,\infty)$.

*Proof:* By continuity, we have either $h(x)>x$ or $h(x)<x$ for all $x>B$. In the former case, we observe that $h$ is a bijection on $(B,\infty)$, and thus we have a $h^{-1}$ is well defined with $h^{-1}(x)<x$ for all $x>B$. We also note that $f(h^{-1}(x)) = f(x)$ for all $x$.

Pick $\epsilon>0$. Then there exists $B'>B$ such that, for all $x\in(B,B')$, $|f(x) - f(B)|<\epsilon$. If we pick $x>B$ arbitrary, we observe that either $h^n(x)$ decreases to $B$, or $h^{-n}(x)$ decreases to $B$ (depending on whether $h(x)<x$ or $h(x)>x$ for $x>B$). Thus, we have for some $z\in\mathbb Z$, $h^z(x) \in(B,B')$. Therefore $$
|f(x)-f(B)| = |f(h^z(x))-f(B)|<\epsilon
$$
Since $x>B$ was arbitrary, we conclude $|f(x)-f(B)| <\epsilon$ for all $x>B$. Letting $\epsilon$ go to $0$, we conclude $f(x)=f(B)$ for any $x>B$.

---

*Proof of claim:* Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function satisfying $f(x)=f(x^a f(x))$ for all $x\in(0,\infty)$. It is straightforward from here to show that $f$ has the desired form. We note that $f(x)=\frac1{x^{a-1}}$ is equivalent to $x$ being a fixed point of $h$. By Lemmas 2 and 3, there exists a closed interval $I$ such that $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^{a-1}}$ for all $x\in I$, and $f(x)\ne \frac{1}{x^{a-1}}$ for all $x\notin I$. By Lemma 4, if $f$ is constant to the right of $I$. Suppose the left endpoint of $I$ is $A>0$. By the reflection principle, we have that $\bar{f}$ is equal to $\frac1{x^{a-1}}$ in the interval $1/I$. Thus, by Lemma 4, $\bar{f}$ is constant for $x>\frac1A$, which implies that $f$ is constant for $x\in(0,A]$. Using continuity of $f$, we can see what the constant values are to the right and left of $I$ and therefore $f$ must have the claimed form for some $c_1,c_2$. Q.E.D.

Comment: Very great proof, thank you very much. It's a challenging functional equation